# Simplify JavaScript regexp

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I simplify my regexp `(^(\w+)\/(\w+)\/(\d+)$|^(\w+)\/(\w+)\/$|^(\w+)\/(\w+)$)` to match examples like `controller/action(/id)`? My current regex looks so long and complex :(

Matching examples:

```
controller/action
controller/action/
controller/action/123
```

Non-matching:

```
controller/
controller/action/action
controller/action/123/
controller/action/123/456
```

Comment: Does `Non-matching:` mean you do not want to match them?

Comment: Will they all start controller/action?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes, sorry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following regex featuring *optional groups*:

```
^(\w+)\/(\w+)(?:\/(\d+)?)?$
             ^^^       ^ ^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xE1kX1/1)

This regex matches:

- `^` - start of a string
- `(\w+)` - one or more alphanumeric or underscore characters
- `\/` - a `/` symbol
- `(\w+)`  - one or more alphanumeric or underscore characters
- `(?:\/(\d+)?)?` - an optional (one or zero occurrences) sequence (due to `(?:...)?` construct, a non-capturing group `(?:...)` + a `?` - one or zero - quantifier) matching

  - `\/` - a forward slash
  - `(\d+)?` - optional *capturing* group matching one or more digits (but this group can be missing since the `?` quantifier is applied to the whole group `(...)`)
- `$` - end of string anchor.

Comment: Just a smidge faster than I was!

Comment: @Trasiva: I hope you were also going to write the explanation like mine. If you are, I can delete my answer.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I was, but you got there first (I already nuked my answer). To the victor go the spoils.